# How to hide or supresss sql query output from the log file (spool file ) in sqlplus

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I’m doing performance testing for my application. I gathered around 100 queries from the application and wanted execute the queries exactly as it's being executed through the application. 
As some quires are giving more than 1000 records, I wanted to hide the sql output in log file.
I just wanted to collect Elapsed Time and Explain Plan.

**Sql Template File:**

```
spool &1


set timing on
set linesize 100
set pagesize 5000
set termout off
set echo on

set autotrace on exp stat

define sql_version = '0.1';


set echo on;
set heading off;
set feedback off;
set verify off;
set timing off;
select  ' Baseline SQL Testing - Version &sql_version : Date - ' || sysdate from dual;
set timing on;
set verify on;
set feedback on;
set heading on;
set echo on;


spool off;
exit;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
set autotrace traceonly exp stat
```

will cause SQL*Plus not to print the results of the query.  It sounds like that's what you're looking for.